# dplyr: select all variables except for those contained in vector

Tags: r, select, dplyr

This should be a simple issue but I am struggling.

I have a vector of variable names that I want to exclude from a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(50), nrow = 10, ncol = 5))
names(df) <- paste0(rep("variable_", 5), 1:5)

excluded_vars <- c("variable_1", "variable_3")
```

I would have thought that just excluding the object in the select statement with `-` would have worked:

```
select(df, -excluded_vars)
```

But I get the following error:

> Error in -excluded_vars : invalid argument to unary operator

the same is true when using `select_()`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`select(df, -any_of(excluded_vars))`
is now the safest way to do this (the code will not break if a variable name that doesn't exist in df is included in `excluded_vars`)

Answer (score 30):

You need to use the `one_of` function:

```
select(df, -one_of(excluded_vars))
```

See the section on Useful Functions in the `dplyr` documentation for [select](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html#details) for more about selecting based on variable names.

Comment: Thanks. But why does `select(df, -excluded_vars)` throw an error but `select(df, excluded_vars)` does not?

Comment: From the documentation for `select`: "Note that except for :, - and c(), all complex expressions are evaluated outside the data frame context." I think what this means is that the `-` symbol does not evaluate its argument when used in `select`. The call to `one_of` is what evaluates your argument.

Answer (score 13):

As of a more recent version of dplyr, the following now works:

```
select(df, -excluded_vars)
```

Comment: this made me happy

Answer (score 9):

You are almost there just use `-c()` in the `excluded_vars`.
Like this:

```
select(df, -c(excluded_vars))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `select_`, you could simply use `setdiff`.

```
select_(df, .dots = setdiff(colnames(df), excluded_vars))
```

Comment: The underscored `dplyr` functions are now depreciated in favor of the tidyr evaluation scheme.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? There is a need to pre-build the column list vector and you'll have to rename the column aligned to its actual order, but it might work?

```
cc1 <- c("id")
nm <- names(df)
cc2 <- setdiff(nm, cc1)

select(df, .cols=c(everything(), -cc1)) %>% rename_with(~ cc2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
df %>% dplyr::select(colname)
```

Some packages also have select function and this may be the problem, that's why you need to mention package.

Answer (score 0):

The `select(... -one_of())` method was giving me an error

> `(unused argument (-one_of(excluded_vars))`

`df[, -which(names(df) %in% excluded_vars)]` worked for me instead (R 4.0.3)

Answer (score -1):

Just simply use the the negation operator as:
`select(df, !c(col1, col2, col3))`

Comment: doesn't work with quoted column names `select(c("col1","col2"))`. Works with unquoted column names, `select(c(col1, col2))` but this is not what OP asked about.